# Get COM interface without QueryInterface

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, com-interop

I'm working with a native C++ dll from C#. On the C++ side there's a class that only implements one interface and IUnknown but its QueryInterface returns E_NOINTERFACE for anything other than IUnknown.

On the C# side I'm calling a method in the dll that returns an instance of this class, but even if I declare the parameter as ISomeInterface .NET still calls QueryInterface which results in an exception. E.g.:

```
[ComImport, Guid(" ... ")]
public interface ISomeInterface { ... }

[DllImport("mylib.dll")]
public static extern void GetThing([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out ISomeInterface thing);
```

calling `GetThing` throws `InvalidCastException` with message "This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{ ... }' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800040002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."

If I change the type to object

```
public static extern void GetThing([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object thing);
```

..then calling `GetThing` succeeds but trying to cast the resulting `System.__ComObject` to `ISomeInterface` throws the same exception.

I tried every different `InterfaceType` attribute on the interface definition but always get the same exception.

I also tried defining the interface as an abstract class:

```
[ComImport, Guid(" ... "), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public abstract class ISomeInterface { ... }
```

Calling `GetThing` then succeeds and I get an instance of `ISomeInterface` but as soon as I call any method it throws a `BadImageFormatException` with message "Bad IL format."

And I tried every different `ClassInterfaceType` attribute with the same results.

Is there any way this class can be used from C# without modifying the C++ code to fix its QueryInterface implementation?

Comment: Well that's unusual for a COM object to just recognise `IUnknown` and nothing else, any reason for that?  Just so you know, the act of c# code _casting_ an `object` to `ISomeInterface` **will** end up calling `QueryInterface` behind the scenes (when the object is a COM object of course) so that is to be expected.  If you have access to the c++ code you should fix it.

Comment: On the C++ side `ISomeInterface` is the default interface so they're able to use it without `QueryInterface` - I'll change the C++ as well but would ideally get it working with this version for compatibility

Comment: _"is the default interface"_ - Hmm that behavior may only work by default for scripting languages.  Also, if it were the case why then do you get an `E_NOINTERFACE` error?  Anyway, try updating the c++ code, due to the nature of COM it is unlikely you'll break compatibility unless you change GUIDs; interfaces etc which in this case is not a requirement

Comment: I've actually modified the C++ code, rebuilt and confirmed that I can get the class and use it in C# - but I'm still interested in any way to get it working without having to distribute a new/unofficial build of this dll

Comment: You make a very curious statement in your opening paragraph. If calling QueryInterface on a COM interface pointer returns E_NOINTERFACE for a given interface, then **by definition** according to the COM rules, that object **does not** implement that interface. If your object "pretends" that it implements that interface, it necessarily does so by breaking the rules of COM, and any functionality you get out of it is essentially *undefined behavior*. Such C++ "COM object" is broken.

Answer (score 0):

With this approach you mentioned:

```
public static extern void GetThing([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object thing);
```

...assuming you are using .NET 4+ try the following:

```
object thing;
GetThing (out thing); // prefix me with the class defining the `DllImport`
dynamic d = thing;
d.DoSomething();  //  CHANGE DoSomething() to a known method that ISomeInterface exposes
```

The behavior of `dynamic` with COM is that no typelibrary is required ahead of time.  You **will not see statement completion/Intellisense** in Visual Studio as you type your code for the methods on the dynamic object but the code **will compile**.  It will be evaluated at runtime. Hopefully that will bypass `QueryInterface()` and will make use of the `default(ISomeInterface )` that you indicated your COM class is decorated with.

OP:

> On the C++ side ISomeInterface is the default interface

OP:

> ...but I'm still interested in any way to get it working without having to distribute a new/unofficial build of this dll

If this works then no change to the COM DLL is required

Comment: `dynamic` in the case of COM is based on IDispatch I believe, so I don't think it will work here since there is no mention of IDispatch being implemented. But this is indeed a case of working with COM "without queryinterface".

Comment: @SimonMourier Yeah that's my fear too.  I'm hoping the `default(...)` may help. :)

Comment: @SimonMourier it casts to dynamic fine but then invoking a method just throws with 'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'doStuff'.. examining the C++ code it does not appear to implement IDispatch either

Comment: @gordy - I'm not surprised, as the COM implementation you have seems pretty funky. I don't see any solution but fix it.

Comment: oops I replied to Simon instead of @MickyD

Answer (score 0):

According to the rules of COM, an object **by definition** implements an interface **only if** calling QueryInterface on *any* interface pointer to that object with the UUID of the sought interface returns a corresponding new (AddRef'd) interface pointer (by which of course I mean returning S_OK and providing the interface pointer via the second argument).<sup>1</sup>

> ... there's a class that only implements one interface and IUnknown but its QueryInterface returns E_NOINTERFACE for anything other than IUnknown.

No, that's incorrect. That object does not implement such interface. If the object is "pretending" that it implements that interface, but does not follow the rules of COM, then that object has a major bug and is broken. Any functionality you happen to get from such situation is essentially *undefined behavior*.

Specifically, it is illegal for a method to return an interface pointer of type `ISomething` if calling QueryInterface on that pointer with `ISomething` returns E_NOINTERFACE (See corollary on the footnote). You have to fix the C++ implementation of that object.

---

<sup>1</sup> There a couple of subtle points:

First, curiously the object doesn't have to decide whether it implements a given interface until someone *asks for it* (although most objects of course have a hardcoded list of interfaces).

Second, once the object has made its mind and announced the decision about a given interface (by either returning a new interface pointer, or E_NOINTERFACE), that particular object can never change its mind for the rest of its lifetime and must always provide the same answer. As a corollary, calling QueryInterface from a given interface pointer, asking for the *same* interface, **must succeed**. This is where your object is broken.

Third, I intentionally said "*any*" interface pointer: for example, if an object implements five interfaces beyond IUnknown, when asked about a 6th interface, it must provide the same answer when asked from any pointer to any of the five other interfaces, as well as from an IUnknown pointer. That is, all implemented interfaces must be reachable from all other interfaces.

Finally, notice that I've been talking about *objects*, not *CoClasses*. CoClasses, default interfaces, registry entries, type libraries, *et al*, those are all (somewhat optional) mechanisms that exist for the benefit of the standard "COM factory" infrastructure, and to assist the developers' tooling. Once you get an interface pointer to an object from that infrastructure, all there is is interface pointers and the underlying objects (which means that the phrase "is the default interface" is irrelevant, and does not absolve the object from following the rules of COM interfaces)

i recommend Don Box's "Essential COM", where you can find all this spelled out in great detail.